# loop over array matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, crop

I am detecting circles in an image. I return circle radii and X,Y of the axis. I know how to crop 1 circle no problem with formula:
`X-radius, Y-radius, width=2*r,height=2*r` using `imcrop`.
My problem is when I get returned more than 1 circle. 
I get returned circle radii in an array `radiiarray`.
I get returned circle centers in `centarray`.
When i `disp(centarray)`, It looks like this:

```
146.4930  144.4943
610.0317  142.1734
```

When I check `size(centarray)` and `disp` it i get:

```
2 2
```

So I understand first column is X and second is Y axis values. So first circle center would be 146,144.
I made a loop that works for only 1 circle. "-------" is where I'm unsure what to use to get: 
note: radius = r

1st circle)

```
            X = centarray(1)-r;
            Y = centarray(3)-r;
            Width =2*r;
            Width =2*r;
```

2nd circle)

```
            X = centarray(2);
            Y = centarray(4);
            Width =2*r;
            Width =2*r;
```

How would I modify the "------" parts for my code? I also would like that if there are 3+ circles the loop would work as Im getting sometimes up to 9 circles from an image.

```
B = imread('p5.tif');
centarray = [];
centarray = [centarray,centers];
radiiarray = [];
radiiarray = [radiiarray,radii];

for j=1:length(radiiarray)

x = centarray((------))-radiiarray(j); %X value to crop
y = centarray((------))-radiiarray(j);    %Y value to crop

width = 2*radiiarray(j);            %WIDTH
height = 2*radiiarray(j);           %HEIGHT

K = imcrop(B, [x y width height]);
end
```

My full code, which doesnt work, as I realized why when i saw the way values are stored...:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DETECT + GET X Y WIDTH HEIGHT OF CIRCLES
I = imread('p5.tif');
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(I);title('Original Image'); 
%sharpen edges
B = imsharpen(I);
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(B);title('sharpened edges');


%find circles
Img = im2bw(B(:,:,3));
minRad = 20;
maxRad = 90;
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Img, [minRad maxRad], ...
                                    'ObjectPolarity','bright','sensitivity',0.84);
imagesc(Img);
viscircles(centers, radii,'Color','green');
%nuber of circles found


%arrays to store values for radii and centers
centarray = [];
centarray = [centarray,centers];
radiiarray = [];
radiiarray = [radiiarray,radii];
sc = size(centarray);
disp(sc)
disp(centarray)
disp(radiiarray)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%CROP USING VALUE FROM ARRAYS NUMBER OF TIMES THERE ARE CENTERS(number of
%circles)


for j=1:length(radiiarray)


    x = centarray((2*j)-1)-radiiarray(j); %X value to crop
    y = centarray((2*j))-radiiarray(j);    %Y value to crop 
    width = 2*radiiarray(j);            %WIDTH
    height = 2*radiiarray(j);           %HEIGHT
    disp(x)
    disp(y)
    disp(centarray)
    %crop using values
    K = imcrop(B, [x y width height]);
    %togray
    gray = rgb2gray(K);
    subplot(2,2,3);imshow(K);title('cropped before bw');
    Icorrected = imtophat(gray, strel('disk', 15));
    %to black and white
    black = im2bw(Icorrected);
    subplot(2,2,4);imshow(black);title('sharpened edges');
    %read
    results = ocr(black); 
    number = results.Text;
    %display value
    disp(number)

end
```

Any help on how to create this kind of loop is appreciated as I just have no more ideas or cant find answer to this..

**EDIT**
**SOLUTION**

Hi, answer is to treat matrix as 2 dimensional.

```
for j=1:length(radiiarray)
x=centarray(j,1)
y=centarray(j,2)
width = radiiarray(j)
height = radiiarray(j)
end
```

as j increases values update correctly now.

Comment: If you treat the array as 2-dimensional it will make your life much easier. For the first circle, the center is `centarray(1,1)` and the radius is `centarray(1,2)`. For the second circle, the center is `centarray(2,1)` and the radius is `centarray(2,2)`. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/array-indexing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is to treat matrix as 2 dimensional.

```
for j=1:length(radiiarray)
x=centarray(j,1)
y=centarray(j,2)
width = radiiarray(j)
height = radiiarray(j)
end
```

as j increases values update correctly now.

Thanks for @beaker for his comment! Thats why I figured it out